# MySQL select in column search

Tags: mysql, search, sql

I've a table which has data something like below. I want to get rows which contains in category column '2'? How shold I set the query? I need that for update the row. The category column has 'text' type.

```
id  category
-------------------
13  -1-,
14  -2-,
15  -1-,-2-,-3-,-4-,
16  -2-,-4-,
```

After update the data should be like that:

```
id  category
-------------------
13  -1-,
14  -5-,
15  -1-,-5-,-3-,-4-,
16  -5-,-4-,
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/). Also, you should normalize your data. This is a poor way to structure your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select those categories like this:

```
select * from your_table where category like '%-2-%'
```

But your example looks like you want to replace `2` with `5`. It can be done like this:

```
update your_table set category = replace(category, '-2-', '-5-')
```

That way you need no `where`clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE category LIKE '%-2-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category LIKE '%2%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category like '%-2-%'
```